# Using the AppHarbor oauth api from a desktop app

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, appharbor

The documentation for the AppHarbour [oauth API](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/oauth-v2) only shows how to perform oauth within a web site, i.e. using a `redirect_uri`

```
GET https://appharbor.com/user/authorizations/new?client_id=:client_id&redirect_uri=:http://mysite.com/home/auth
```

This ends up re-directing to http://mysite.com/home/auth?&code=ACCESS_CODE

But is there a way to get the `ACCESS_CODE` value back as part of the GET? I'm looking to use the AppHarbour api within a desktop app. I can use an embedded web-browser to open a web page so that the user can authenticate my app, but I don't have a re-direct url for it to return to?

How can I use the api to do this?

Comment: We've improved the SDK to make this simpler, check out the blog post: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/06/21/oauth-for-net-desktop-applications

Comment: Nice, thanks for that. Yeah you're right, that's exactly the reason I was trying to do this `We only realized the need for a non-web OAuth flow after announcing the AppHarbor API contest where we gamely suggested you guys build various desktop apps using the API, without providing a useful way to authenticate these kinds of apps.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: We've pushed an update to the SDK to make desktop client auth really easy. Check out the blog post: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/06/21/oauth-for-net-desktop-applications

AppHarbor does not yet support the [specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25#section-4.1.3) for getting tokens from non-web apps.

The AppHarbor CLI has a web service that it uses to retrieve token, you could stand up your own. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/appharbor/appharbor-cli/blob/master/src/AppHarbor/Commands/LoginUserCommand.cs). DON'T use this web service to get tokens, you should have your own service using the correct client id.

We're looking at implementing the correct flow for non-web apps.